# How to update MS Access database in asp.net ? No solution working

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access

I am trying the following code. It is throwing an exception "update statement incorrect syntax".

```
public bool add(string Username, string Pasword)
{   
     string myconnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\HUZAI\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\APFinal Practise\\APFinal Practise\\App_Data\\users.mdb";

     using (OleDbConnection con=new OleDbConnection(myconnection))
     {
         OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE users SET password = @pass WHERE username = @name", con);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", Password);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", name);

         if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
         {
             return true;
         }

         return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know why it is not updating the MS Access database. Table users contain username and password field only. Both columns are of `text` type. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to obtain the latest service pack for the Microsoft Jet 4.0 Database Engine and keep a Jet 4.0 database in top working condition.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/239114

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303528

Comment: can you tell me reason for error ?